# Limit of Identity Function vs. limit of Squaring Function

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, probability-limit-theorems

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} x = a$$ and
>
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} x^2 = a^2$$

$f(x)=x^2=x \times x$, i.e.: two identity functions. I'm a bit confused on how $x^2$ can be interpreted as being similar to the identity function $x$ if $x^2$ is clearly doubling (squaring) values and so is not the identity function.
Of course I can solve these types of problems because teachers say to "just plug in", but maybe you can elaborate more on these limit laws (Identity Law and Power Law) or abstract them, my teacher doesn't go into abstractions.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "two identity functions"?

Comment: @TrevorWilson $x$ is the identity function, and $x \times x$ is two identity functions. This is from my notes, not my idea.

Comment: It seems to me that the only similarity between the identity function and the squaring function that shows up here is that they are both continuous (at an arbitrary point $a$) as Berci has pointed out.  It's true for lots of other functions also, for example constant functions, the function $f$ given by $f(x) = -x$, _etc._  If you replace the squaring function with one of those functions, is the result still confusing to you?

Comment: I see, thanks. So if we know that the function is continuous, we can evaluate the limit of the function at $a$ as $x$ approaches $a$? So the limit will be $f(a)$ as $x \rightarrow a$? @TrevorWilson

Comment: That's right; for continuous functions the limit as $x \to a$ can be found by simply "plugging in $a$."

Answer (score 1):

These could be also said in equivalent form as both functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ are *continuous*:

A function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous iff $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$.